# what is the best way to sync data in different devices

Tags: flutter, websocket, diff

I am written a GTD app using flutter, now I want to sync the todo list for different devices. is there any sync algorithm to do this? I want to using websocket to sync in real time, and maintain a queue with a sequence number to record all operation, each client using the client latest sequence number to check the server side lastest sequence number, if client sequence number less than server side sequence number, then execute the queue operation in the current client. what is the best way to sync data in different devices?